# python Django Pasar valores de un text box a función

Tags: javascript, python, django

Ojalá puedan ayudarme por que he no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo.
Entiendo que a la hora de usar formularios con Django existen dos maneras, una es con los formularios generados por los modelos(bd) y otros sin los modelos, todo desde el forms.py, desconozco si existe la posibilidad de pasar parámetros a una función desde un html externo (Que no este estipulado en el forms).

Dicho esto he intentado hacer un form, en forms.py que no dependa de un modelo, lo cual me genera un hermoso form de un solo text box, funciona bien pongo un valor y lo imprime en la misma pagina o en la que yo le indique, pero resulta que tengo el siguiente inconveniente, necesito una función que sume todos los valores pasados por uno o mas text box, por ejemplo:

```
def hola(return,*args):
    sum(args)...
    ...
```

Hasta aquí todo esta bien, el siguiente código es un java script que vi en w3schools y creo que es lo que necesito, lo agregue al template, lo que hace es básicamente agregar un text o box o tantos como yo quiera ademas del que ya esta definido teniendo el código de la siguiente manera.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p>Click the button to create a Text Field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", "Hello World!");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Lo que no tengo idea es como pasar esos valores de los textbox generados por el botón a la función **args, como hago que esos valores pasen por ahi junto con el valor de {{form}}

Teóricamente al final del día lo tengo renderizado de la siguiente manera.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='1ZpJLsYEZBeSIPjqzIWmfGfO4UGcSYQm' />
    <tr><th><label for="id_your_name">NOMBRE EN FORMS:</label></th><td><input id="id_your_name" maxlength="100" name="your_name" type="text" /></td></tr>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p>Click the button to create a Text Field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", "Hello World!");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

¡Ayuda porfa!

Answer (score 1):

Primero cuando el usuario presiona el botón "submit" del formulario el explorador armará una petición HTTP utilizando el método POST y la ruta que esté indicada en el atributo "action" de la etiqueta form.

Los campos que tu agregaste mediante JavaScript también son agregados en la petición, por lo que estarán disponibles en la variable **POST** del objeto **HttpRequest** en la vista.

Ejemplo:

Sigo con tu ejemplo, pero imaginemos que el **action** de tu formulario tiene la ruta /sumar_argumentos

```
<form action="/sumar-argumentos">
    <!--tu codigo -->
</form>
```

Aahora en tu aplicación django registras la función que le dará repuesta en `urls.py`.

```
url(r'^sumar-argumentos', views.funcion_prueba)
```

En tu función puedes acceder a los atributos enviados al formulario de la siguiente forma:

```
def funcion_prueba(request):
    response = ''
    if validar_valores(request.POST):
        for key, value in request.POST.items():
            if key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
                response += 'key:%s value:%s\n' % (key, value)
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

La variable **`request.POST`** almacena un diccionario con todos los parámetros recibidos en la petición, pero no es buena práctica acceder a ellos directamente, por eso coloqué el método **`validar_valores`**, donde debes filtrar los parámetros recibidos.

También puedes usar un Formulario de django para hacer la validación: crearías una clase que herede de `django.forms.Form` y personalizas la validación para que tome en cuenta los atributos dinámicos.

Resumí algunas cosas por tiempo pero espero de una idea.

Comment: @Rodrigo Calderon, por favor ve esta respuesta, tienes un problema parecido en tu javascript [inclusion de inputs dinamicos](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26733/15167) ya edité la respuesta para preveer el token csrf.

Answer (score 0):

en verdad agradezco mucho tu tiempo y orientación :)

Mira. Si, en efecto el forms que estoy utilizando si es de django, hice lo que pusiste lineas arriba y parece funcionar bien, sin embargo al momento de hacer el reder me imprime el token.

Expongo el código con el que cuento, en verdad espero puedas ayudarme por que llevo días con esto.

forms.py

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Puntos a sumar', max_length=100, initial='2,4,6,8,10')
```

views.py

```
def funcion_prueba(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        response = ''
        for key, value in request.POST.items():
            response += 'key:%s value:%s\n' % (key, value)
        return HttpResponse(response)       

    else:
        form = NameForm() #hacemos formulario en blanco


    return render(request, 'datos.html', {'form': form})
```

datos.html

```
<form action="/sumar-argumentos" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p>AGREGAR VALOR</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Agregar</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", "0");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Lo cual cuando llego a http://127.0.0.1:8000/sumar-argumentos me muestra la pantalla para ingresar datos.

Todo de maravilla hasta este momento.

## [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando renderiza, si pone el codigo que pongo en el label del form pero no los dinámicos.

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acto seguido imprime el token:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedas echar una mano.

Muchísimas Gracias por tu atención.