# Obtener valores de un formulario

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de sacar los values de un form que no está en el forms.py, además de esto tiene un botón para agregar un valor más, lo que pretendo es únicamente imprimir en la pantalla los valores ingresados, desgraciadamente no he podido hacer que funcione.

Mensaje de error

> local variable 'response' referenced before assignment

urls

```
url(r'^test', views.test),
```

views

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        response = ''
        for key, value in request.POST.items():
            response += '%s %s\n' % (key, value)

    return HttpResponse(response)




    return render(request, 'datos2.html')
```

datos2.html

```
<form action="/test" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="eee">
<input type="submit">
</form>


<p>ADD VALUE</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", "0");
    x.setAttribute("name", "eee");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

A la hora de ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error

> local variable 'response' referenced before assignment

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que extraña tu pregunta cuando dices "form que no está en el forms.py". Gasta donde yo sé, todos los FORM (formularios) deben estar en forms.py

Answer (score 1):

Tu return `return HttpResponse(response)` está fuera de el condicional, por llo cual si no entra en el condicional la variable `response` nunca es definida intenta asi...

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        response = ''
        for key, value in request.POST.items():
            response += '%s %s\n' % (key, value)

        return HttpResponse(response) # nota, cuatro espacios de mas de indentación

return render(request, 'datos2.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que desea mostrar los valores que fueron agregados de forma dinámica, pero el javascript no está agregado los valores en el formulario si no en el body, lo que ocaciona que no sean enviados en la petición, deberia ser así:

```
<form id="test" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>

<p>ADD VALUE</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        form = document.getElementById('test')
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "text");
        x.setAttribute("value", "0");
        x.setAttribute("name", "eee");
        form.appendChild(x)
    }
</script>
```

Ahora la lógica para mostrar los valores digamos que está bien pero no  es clara, por eso la cambie un poco:

```
for key, value in request.POST.items():
    response = ''
    if key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
         response += 'llave: %s valor:%s<br>' % (key, value)
```